# two authentication mechanism on a spring boot application (Basic & JWT)

Tags: spring, jwt, basic-authentication

I have a spring boot app, I have just finished implementing a stateless authentication/authorization module based on `jwt`.

This is how I configured my security module:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
}
```

So basically if I want to access the url `/api/jobs` I get a 401 error unless I send the bearer token which I get after a succesfull authentication on `/api/authenticate`.

What I need to know is if it's possible to access `/api/jobs` without supplying the bearer token, using a basic http authentication with a login and passowrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just make sure you have:

```
http.httpBasic();
```

in your configuration. That builder also have other methods to configure the details for basic auth.